# Validation of user keyboard entry in R

Tags: r, validation, recursion

I am developing a MonteCarlo analysis where the user chooses a particular data set. I need to request user input as an integer and then perform data validation on it. For some reason I can't problem solve this code. The validated number defines the input data set which later functions pick as required.

Initially the validation was written as a recursive function but that proved troublesome so it was converted to 2 functions.

The idea is that grepl() separates everything except positive integers. Then is.na() tests for NA. Then %in% tests for membership of a vector of possible values. If any test fails the user is asked to try again via an appropriate error message and an instruction.

I tested it by repeatedly making wrong entries. What happens is that the function gets it wrong and exits after a few attempts.

If you are able please show how to modify the code or how to do it in better style. I have web searched for data validation etc. but found nothing of use.
Many thanks. Scriptham.

```
################################################################################
##                                                                            ##
##  Function to obtain user input for each run                                ##
##  Input should be all the possibilities in basicdata.id                     ##
##  These are then processed so that the user chooses the one of interest     ##
##  The keyboard entry is checked for a whole number                          ## 
##     and for being in the set of basicdata.id                               ##
##                                                                            ##
##****************************************************************************##

## Possible Messages
 vec  <- seq(1,7)    # For testing 
 msgn <- paste(vec,collapse=",") 
 msg0 <- "Available basic data row numbers are:\n"
 msg1 <- "What is the basic data row number?\n"
 msg2 <- "That was not an integer.\n"
 msg3 <- "Integer supplied is not among the basic data number choices.\n" 
 msg4 <- "Type Here > " 
 msg5 <- "That was not a number.\n" 
 msg6 <- "That was NA"
 msg  <- paste(msg0, msgn, msg1)

## The input is supposed to be in some vector of integers 
##  which will always be small in value


fnTestInt <- function(txt)     # Recursive
{ 
  x <- ""                       # for troubleshooting
  x <- readline(prompt=txt) 
  print(paste("x value = ", x)) # for troubleshooting

## tests if input is not a number, rejects text, punctuation, decimals     
  if (grepl("\\D", x, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=FALSE, fixed=FALSE, useBytes=FALSE)) { 
  return(5)

## tests for na, (actually NA), rejects if NA
  } else if (is.na(x)) {
  return(6)

## converts from string to integer, tests if input is outwith the allowed set   
  } else if (!(as.integer(x) %in% vec)) {    
  return(3)

  } else {

## If it reaches here it has passed all the tests
return(as.integer(x))
}
}

#y <- as.integer(fnReadInt(msg))                                               #
# Now because it is a recursive function it may have multiple returns          #
#  and will therefore on completion give multiple values.                      #
#                                                                              #                                              
##   Not WORKING 21/04/2017   But  NOT Yet Complete                           ##
###   Not WORKING 27/04/2017   But  NOT Yet Complete                         ###
################################################################################


fnReadIn <- function(txt)          {
          if (fnTestInt(txt) == 5) {
      return (fnTestInt(paste(msg5, msg)))

   } else if (fnTestInt(txt) == 6) {
      return (fnTestInt(paste(msg6, msg)))

   } else if (fnTestInt(txt) == 3) {   
      return (fnTestInt(paste(msg3, msg)))

   } else 
      return ("Finished")
   }  

## to run.     
fnReadIn(msg)
```

Comment: Have you done any searching? This seems to be a search strategy to consider: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20%22user%20input%22

Comment: Yes. I searched on R data validation, on R recursive functions, and similar.  When written as a recursive function and tested with several wrong inputs followed by a correct input the output cycles through the wrong answers first. Does that symptom mean anything to anyone?

Comment: Having slept on the problem I have come to it fresh this morning and rewritten the function. It is working now. Unfortunately I have no idea why it didn't work yesterday. Sorry to have troubled you and thanks. Scriptham

Comment: I've voted to close as no longer reproducible. The code might have been more readable if you had used the `switch` function. instead of the if-else chaining for the numeric entries.